# Pickling an XGBoost model makes it give different results when predicting

Tags: python, xgboost

I've tried to reproduce the issue with sinthetic data with no luck, it happens with a particular (private) dataset

Data generation

```
import pickle as pkl
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from xgboost import XGBRegressor

NOISE = 25

def real_vs_fitted(reg, X,y):
    fitted = reg.predict(X)
    real = y
    residual = real - fitted
    plt.scatter(fitted, residual)

    NOISE = 25
    samples = 1000

np.random.seed(42)

# Data
samples = 1000
A = np.random.randint(1,100,samples)
B = np.random.randint(1,100,samples)
C = np.random.randint(1,100,samples)

X = np.stack([A,B,C]).T


y = 3*A + 10*np.log(B) + A*B*C + np.random.normal(0,NOISE,len(X))


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

Training and serializing

```
reg = XGBRegressor()
reg.fit(X_train,y_train)

real_vs_fitted(reg,X_test,y_test)

print(f'Reg object Hash: {hash(reg)}')

with open('model.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    
    pkl.dump(reg, f)
```

Unserializing

```
with open("model.pkl", "rb") as f:
    reg = pkl.load(f)

real_vs_fitted(reg,X_test,y_test)

print(f'Reg object Hash: {hash(reg)}')
```

Hashes are different (I'm assuming it's because some attributes are not saved when serializing, maybe not).
X_test hash by row (pd.util.hash_pandas) is the same too
reg.get_booster().trees_to_dataframe() seems to be the same too

Any clues?